# The calculation of a homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is a question on Massey's *A Basic Course of Algebraic Topology*. I met some problem in calculating a homology group of a specific space when dealing with a question.

Let $X=\{ (x,y,z) \mid xyz=0 \}$ then how to calculate $H_2(X)$?
By the way, are there any widely used important skills in calculating such homology groups?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Do you mean $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:xyz=0\}$?

Comment: Instead of just stating the problem, specify what you've thought about so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: So assuming $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$ then your $X$ deformation retracts onto the singleton $\{(0,0,0)\}$ via $(t,v)\mapsto tv$. All positive homologies are trivial.

Comment: Oh gosh! I guess my brain has been occupied with so many strange ideas, not noticing that the space can be retract to origin!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you actually mean $X=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\ |\ xyz=0\}$ judging from comments (always write down the space you start from). In that situation there's a deformation retraction

$$F:I\times X\to X$$
$$F(t,v)=tv$$

onto the origin $\{(0,0,0)\}$ and so $X$ is contractible.

---

As for the skills/tools. Well there are lots of them, to name few important:

1. homotopy invariance (the one I've used above)
2. [the long exact sequence of homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_homology#Properties)
3. [Mayer-Vietoris sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence)
4. [Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Steenrod_axioms) (which generalizes 1 and 2)
5. [Kunneth formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem)
6. [Hurewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem) (although seems to be more useful for homotopy calculation)
7. [Lefschetz duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_duality)
8. [spectral sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_sequence) (heavy artillery)

and many, many more. The research on the topic is still ongoing, probably will never end.